# Mysql View complex

Tags: mysql, view

```
mytable
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| field1           | field2              |field3           | 
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                | 10                  |                 |
| 1                | 20                  |                 |
| 2                | 100                 |                 |
| 2                | 200                 |                 |
|                  |                     |         1       |
|                  |                     |         2       |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------|
```

I would like to create a view that shows this result

```
myview desired result
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| field1           | field2              |field3           | 
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                | 10                  |                 |
| 1                | 20                  |                 |
| 2                | 100                 |                 |
| 2                | 200                 |                 |
|                  | 30                  |         1       |
|                  | 300                 |         2       |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------|
```

30  is the sum of field2 where field1=1 (value of field3)

300 is the sum of field2 where field1=2 (value of field3)

my mysql query is

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
SELECT
  field1, if(field3>0,sum(field2) where field1=field3,field2), field3 
FROM mytable
```

But not work, I have **NULL** values instead of 30 and 300

Another case:  **Nested situation**
mytable

```
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| field1           | field2              |field3           | 
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                | 10                  |         0       |
| 1                | 20                  |         0       |
| 2                | 100                 |         0       |
| 2                | 200                 |         0       |
| 3                |                     |         1       |
| 3                |                     |         2       |
| 4                |                     |         3       |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------|
```

myview desired result

```
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| field1           | field2              |field3           | 
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                | 10                  |         0       |
| 1                | 20                  |         0       |
| 2                | 100                 |         0       |
| 2                | 200                 |         0       |
| 3                | 30                  |         1       |
| 3                | 300                 |         2       |
| 4                | 330                 |         3       |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------|
```

how do i get the values 30,300 and 330?

Answer (score 0):

Close.  You need to join to get the sum.

```
SELECT m.field1, if(m.field3>0,sum(m2.field2),m.field2) as field2, m.field3
from mytable m
left join mytable m2 on m2.field1=m.field3
group by m.field1, m.field2, m.field3
```

Comment: ysth ....Now I have edited another case. Nested situation

Comment: you should ask a new question.  do add output of `select version();`, and say if there is some maximum number of nested levels.  ideally provide your schema and sample data as create table and inserts in a fiddle, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it

Answer (score 0):

This query assumes that you empyt columns are in fact NULL, else you have to adept the IF clause fot field3

This uses teh fact, that you can make a subquery that sus up the values for field2 for a specific mytable field1

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (
>   `field1` INTEGER,
>   `field2` INTEGER,
>   `field3` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO mytable
>   (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '10', NULL),
>   ('1', '20', NULL),
>   ('2', '100', NULL),
>   ('2', '200', NULL),
>   (NULL, NULL, '1'),
>   (NULL, NULL, '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `field1`
> , IF( `field3` IS NOT NULL ,(SELECT SUM(`field2`) FROM mytable WHERE `field1` = t1.`field3`) ,`field2`) 'field2'
> , `field3` 
> FROM mytable t1
> ```
>
> ```
> field1 | field2 | field3
> -----: | -----: | -----:
>      1 |     10 |   null
>      1 |     20 |   null
>      2 |    100 |   null
>      2 |    200 |   null
>   null |     30 |      1
>   null |    300 |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e94444e07481de50b8b9f2014b762c1a)*

Comment: Now I have edited another case. ***Nested situation***

Comment: you have to make a new question and not add new information to your question and change it.

Comment: this has nthing to do with nested it is recursive, that needs mysql 8 or you really short start in hirachical trees. good luck

Comment: Please do accept the answer, like i wrote in the other coment, and when you ask an ew question abut your problem, that will be much mre complicated, you need also to post yor Version of mysql. Like i wirote mysql has much improved such hirachy question bcause it ca make recursive cte

Comment: and when i think about it, when you write a INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger that automatically sums up everything, so you don't need this complex queries. think about it.